# Angularjs - MultiSelect dropdown options not displayed in IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My application has a multiselect dropdown which displays countries. This drop down is displaying properly in Chrome and in IE it displays options as below:

[image]

I am using below code (tried changing value in select to ng-value and not worked)-

**HTML**

```
<select multiple name="multiCountries" ng-model="vm.country.countryList">
   <option ng-repeat="option in vm.country.filteredList" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can try using `ng-options` within the `select` element. `<select multiple name="multiCountries" ng-model=vm.country.countryList" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in vm.country.filteredList"></select>`

Comment: Thanks, Its worked. Can you please add this as answer so i will choose that..

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer if you would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-options` instead of doing an `ng-repeat` on the option element itself. The general format for this is [option value] as [option text] for [option] in [list of options].

**.html**

```
<select multiple name="multiCountries" ng-model=vm.country.countryList" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in vm.country.filteredList"></select>
```